# Deducción de tipos en clase plantilla no funciona con variables miembro

Tags: c++, c++17

Estoy probando las *cositas* nuevas de C++17. Concretamente, [Class template argument deduction (CTAD)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)

Este pequeño ejemplo funciona correctamente:

```
#include <vector>

template< typename T > class vectorWrapper {
  const std::vector< T > *_real;
public:
  vectorWrapper( const std::vector< T > &vec ) : _real( &vec ) { }
  T operator[]( unsigned idx ) const { return _real->at( idx ); }
};

int main( ) {
  std::vector< int > vector;
  vectorWrapper vwrapper = vector;

  return 0;
}
```

Ahora, quiero utilizarlo también **para declarar variables-miembro**. Simplemente, añado una clase extra al código anterior:

```
#include <vector>

template< typename T > class vectorWrapper {
  const std::vector< T > *_real;
public:
  vectorWrapper( const std::vector< T > &vec ) : _real( &vec ) { }
  T operator[]( unsigned idx ) const { return _real->at( idx ); }
};

struct Test {
private:
  std::vector< int > _vector;

public:
  vectorWrapper vw = _vector;
};

int main( ) {
  std::vector< int > vector;
  vectorWrapper vwrapper = vector;
  Test t;

  return 0;
}
```

<sub>**Nota**: se puede [<kbd>probar aquí</kbd>](https://tio.run/##dY/dSsQwEEbv8xQDglSXgl4J/XuKghciS5zGEkjTkEyqUvbVrdPGoovuXYac88036FzeIy7LlbZoYqegmhTS6BshSA3OSFIV0IdTVg4KWmgAjQwBEvXopXPKwywAcLSBIFBXFOmz2vDbo1fSlMLFF6OxYPBMzS551zzADRSw@dk@z3DiiBZGdiXDT88ZRBt0b1UHuntnJAXO4BVFb5OfN5Ky9F9ywqkUIpCPSNCqFRbO64lvXfudVdGWuMwxjWxdOAOmN6h/sDV/NQepbba2/j92x/@GfT/qX8hWlDgY9svueNGyfOKrkX1Ycl5Q4@Fw//AF).</sub>

Pero al compilador no le hace mucha gracia:

> error: invalid use of template-name `vectorWrapper` without an argument list

El error hace referencia al punto del código en el que intento deducir los tipos en una variable-miembro:

```
public:
  vectorWrapper vw = _vector;
};
```

- ¿ Qué estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema de tu ejemplo es que `vw` es una variable miembro que se inicializa implícitamente a partir de otra variable miembro. Esta inicialización requiere de dos pasos fundamentales:

- Declaración del tipo
- Invocación del constructor

El origen del problema está en que, a la hora de ejecutar el primer paso, necesario para reservar espacio para el objeto dentro de la clase, el compilador desconoce la especialización de la plantilla.

¿Y eso?

Bueno, en el ejemplo has optado por una inicialización implícita en la cabecera... esto el compilador lo convierte en lo siguiente:

```
struct Test {
private:
  std::vector< int > _vector;

public:

   vectorWrapper vw;

   Test()
     : vw{_vector}
   { }
};
```

Y aquí el problema se ve más claramente... Atendiendo a la declaración de `vw`, ¿De qué tipo es exactamente? Pues eso.

Resumiendo: Esta nueva característica de la que hablas solo se puede aprovechar para variables que, bien se encuentran dentro de funciones, bien son variables globales. Las variables miembro no pueden beneficiarse de esta característica porque su declaración y su inicialización se realizan en momentos diferentes

Comment: **Excelente** explicación. Con el ejemplo que has puesto, se comprende **perfecto**.

Comment: @Trauma Aprovechando, si quieres cubrir todas las nuevas características de C++17 en español, puedes revisar el libro **C++17 - La guía completa** (https://leanpub.com/cpp17es/) en Leanpub para la versión electrónica o en Amazon (varios países) para la versión impresa.  El capítulo 9 cubre la deducción de argumentos de plantillas de clase.